# SQL Query that fetches All the Names of the Mechanic that have all the skills in the skillsRequired table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Mechanic which has rows like

### MechName            Mechanic Skill

```
    A            Bike Repair
    A            Car Repair
    B            Bike Repair
    B            Car Repair
    B            Oil Change
    C            Oil Change
```

Another Table SkillsRequired

### Skills

```
    Bike Repair
    Oil Change
    Car Repair.
```

Need to Write a Query to Fetch all the Names of the Mechanic That have all the skills listed in the SkillsRequired Table.

ANS: Only B has to be in the result because only B has all the 3 skills required.
PS: Have an idea about a solution invloving groupby and counts but that may not be completely right.

Thanks @inquisitive_mind for the below Solution. But can we formulate this differently? I need another Query that does exactly what the below query does.

```
    select MechName from Skills a join Mechanic b
    on a.Skills = b.MechSkill
    group by Mechname
    having count(MechSkill) = (select count(*) from Skills)
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: I sure hope your real tables don't store those strings in both tables.

Comment: @Rabbit This is for SQL Server

Comment: @SeanLange They are indeed stored in 2 different tables

Comment: You might consider reading up on normalization. Storing text like that in multiple tables is painful. Consider what happens when you have to change the description of a skill. You have to also update it in every other table that references it which defeats the purpose of relational data.

Comment: @SeanLange This is part of an existing system that is given to me and I'm only to write queries without modifying anything. I appreciate your thoughts in the direction though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select MechName from Skills a join Mechanic b
on a.Skills = b.MechSkill
group by Mechname
having count(MechSkill) = (select count(*) from Skills)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Also, do you have any other idea to formulate the same in a different way? I'm looking for multiple implementations of the same use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my response to allow you to search for a combination of items as well.

```
SELECT MechName, COUNT(DISTINCT Skill)
FROM Mechanic
WHERE Skill IN ('Oil Change', 'Car Repair', 'Bike Repair')
GROUP BY MechName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Skill) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Langosta for your response. But what if the skills listed in the skills required table were Car Repair and Bike Repair but the Mechanic had skills Oil Change and Tyre Change. Even though the skills are different the counts would match and give a false positive.

Comment: I've changed to reply so that you might be able to adapt this logic and set a combination of items instead of just ALL items.

Comment: I would like the Where Skill in () Part to be dynamic, It has to fetch all the values from the Skills Required table

Comment: I'm lost as to why the original answer didn't qualify, then, if you really do want ALL Skills. However, feel free to change it to Skill IN (SELECT Skills FROM Skills). This was mostly meant to show you the base logic. You're going to have to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: I was asked to bring in an alternative solution to this as well. Any thoughts on that?